# Methods for solving non-linear ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics

I had the second order non-linear ODE $$f''\left(t\right)f'\left(t\right)=f\left(t\right)^{2}$$
And I managed to reduce it to a first order ODE $$f'\left(t\right)=\left(C^3+f\left(t\right)^{3}\right)^{1/3}$$
and noticed that I can set $C=1$ and reintroduce it at the end, since it just scales the solution. But I'm stuck at this point. Would appreciate any help, thanks.

*I know that $f\left(t\right)=e^{kt}$ is a solution when $k$ is a cube root of unity, but I'm after the general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting $$v(y)=\frac{dy(x)}{dx}$$ then you will getz
$$\frac{dv(y)}{dy}v(y)^2=y^2$$
$$\int\frac{dv(y)}{dy}v(y)^2dy=\int y^2dy$$
$$\frac{v(y)^3}{3}=\frac{y^3}{3}+C_1$$
can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

The first order equation in $f$ is in separated variables. You can write the solution as
$$
\int\frac{df}{\left(C^3+f\left(t\right)^{3}\right)^{1/3}}=t+K
$$
for a constant $K$. Unfortunately, this integral is not expressible in terms of elementary functions. Mathematica gives it in terms of Apell hypergeometric functions.